# Adding Elements of the array

Tags: javascript

```
var arr=[];
var k=0;
document.getElementById("id2").onclick=function(){
if(k<10){
  k++;
  arr.push(document.getElementById("id1").value);
}
document.getElementById("id3").innerHTML=arr;
var sum;
sum=arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
document.getElementById("id4").innerHTML=sum;
}
```

Here,Iam giving several inputs and storing them in arr.
I can display the elements of arr,but I couldn't display the sum of the elements in arr.
If inputs are [1,2,3,4]; the sum is being displayed as 1234 but not 10(1+2+3+4).
Please help me to to do this.

Comment: Hundreds of similar questions on SO, didn't you searched? Anyway, use `sum=arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return +a + +b; });`

Comment: `.value` is a string, you need to convert to an number `arr.push(+document.getElementById("id1").value);`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek,Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your array has is a set of string, not int.

Use `parseInt` to convert it to int before pushing it into an array.

Example

```
arr.push(parseInt(document.getElementById("id1").value));
```